# Олимпиадная задача проходит на 80%

Tags: c++

> Определить координаты малейшего интервала с целочисленными координатами концов, на который приходятся значения элементов действительной последовательности.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double min;
    double max;
    int n;
    double q;

     cin >> n;
     cin >> min;
     max = min;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> q;
        if (q < min) min = q;
        if (q > max) max = q;
    }


    int int_min = min;
    if(min < 0) {
        if (min - int_min != 0) min = int_min - 1;
    } else {
         if (min - int_min != 0) min = int_min;
    }

     int int_max = max;
    if(max < 0) {
        if (max - int_max != 0) max = int_max + 1;
    } else {
         if (max - int_max != 0) max = int_max  + 1;
    }

     cout << min <<" " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ищу минимальный и максимальные елементы и соответственно округляю, задача проходит только на 80%, подскажите, что делаю не так.

Comment: Бррр.... Я один ничего не понял из условия?

Comment: Олимпиадная задача, требующая использования чисел с плавающей точкой - плохая задача

Comment: Опишите ввод, желаемый вывод, теперешний вывод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int int_min = floor(min);
int int_max=ceil(max);
```

Comment: боьшое спасибо.